# Can we perform 'Contains' query on DynamoDB Partition key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a dynamoDB table with 1 Billion records with, Hash column below as partition key.

| Hash | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| hash1 | data |
| hash2 | data |

Now I have a list of hashes (hash1, hashA, bashB) at 1K scale and want to get the data for these hashes from the above table. What would be the fastest way to do this since I need to do this every few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDb [BatchGetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) can be used to get multiple records at once for given keys from multiple tables at once.

For example to do this in NodeJs using [DocumentClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-document-client.html)

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" });
var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
documentClient.batchGet(
  {
    RequestItems: {
      test: {    // 'test' is the table name.
        Keys: [
          {
            id: "1", // 'id' is the hasKey.
          },
          {
            id: "2",
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  function (err, data) {
    console.log("err", err, "data", data);
  }
);
```

Comment: This does have a limitation of 100 items per batch though right? Is there any other faster way?

Comment: True. not just 100 items, but also 16 MB total limit.  it returns `UnprocessedKeys` and we need to re-run query for those un processed keys. I don't think, there is another way to retrieve items by partition key.